# Bash Script to find, process and rename files?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to put together  a script which will run through all the files on my server (under various subdirectories) , look for .jpeg files and run them through a translator which converts them to non progressive jpgs.

I have:

```
 find /home/disk2/ -type f -iname "*.jpg"
```

Which finds all the files.

Then if it finds for example 1.jpg, I need to run:

```
/usr/bin/jpegtrans /file location/1.jpg > /file location/1.jpg.temp
```

The jpegtrans app converts the file to a temp file which needs to replace the original file.
So then I need to delete the original and rename 1.jpg.temp to 1.jpg

```
 rm /file location/1.jpg
 mv /file location/1.jpg.temp /file location/1.jpg
```

I can easily do this for single files but i need to do it for 100's on my server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `find` with `-exec`:

```
find /home/disk2/ -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec sh -c "/usr/bin/jpegtrans {} > {}.temp; mv -f {}.temp {}" \;
```

EDIT: For handling spaces in filenames, say:

```
find /home/disk2/ -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec sh -c "/usr/bin/jpegtrans '{}' > '{}.temp'; mv -f '{}.temp' '{}'" \;
```

Comment: Thanks - it seems to be having problems with spaces in the folders. I've tried putting '{}' > '{}.temp' but that didnt seem to help

Comment: @Greg The edit above contains an example for handling spaces.